# video start playing before Pre-Roll ad in jwplayer 6

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, jwplayer6

I am using jwplayer 6

Issue: The Video start playing before Pre-Roll ad and within the video, pre-roll ad start playing.
I want to pre-roll the ad. Ad must pre-roll before any part of video plays.

Jwplayer configuration:

```
                            jwplayer('vidShow').setup({
                            flashplayer: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',

                            autostart: true,
                            primary: 'flash',
                            file: '$videoURL',
                            //image: '$imageUrl',                                                                
                            height: 392,
                            width: 658,

            advertising: {
            client: 'vast',
            schedule: {
                               myPreroll: 
               {
                                offset: 'pre',
                 tag: '".$theDesktopTag."'
              }
              }
            }   
                        });
```